# SettingWithCopyWarning while using .loc

Tags: python, pandas

Problem is simplified:

I need to extract and modify particular rows of a `DataFrame` based on whether or not the text within a column has a '-' character. The dash and everything beyond needs to be removed and the remaining text needs to be whatever was preceding the '-'.

```
have:
     textcol
0    no dash here
1    one - here

want:
     textcol
0    one
```

here is the code used to recreate my scenario.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['no dash here', 'one - here'], index=[0, 1], columns=['textcol'])
df2 = df[df['textcol'].str.contains('-') == True]
df2.loc[:, ['textcol']] = df2['textcol'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

The resulting `DataFrame` df2 yields the result that I desire, with one exception. Every time I call df2 (or any derivative thereafter) I receive the following `SettingWithCopyWarning`:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation:
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
```

I tried to accomplish what I wanted a different way, and was given a similar error that instructed me to try and use the `.loc()` functionality instead, but I'm still receiving this similar error.

Is there a better, non-error threatening way for me to accomplish this result? I'm afraid something is occurring here that I don't understand and that eventually df2 will not result in what I want. I am also wondering if something like `.query()` would work.

Comment: You've taken a view/copy  when you assigned to `df2` you want to operate directly on the df: `df.loc[df['textcol'].str.contains('-'), 'textcol'] = df['textcol'].str.split('-').str[0]` I think should work

Comment: @EdChum, I still receive the same error :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As mentioned by @EdChum, `df2` is a `view` on `df` as opposed to a `copy`. If you want a `copy`, you can use `.copy()` [(see docs)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.copy.html) and the `SettingWithCopyWarning` disappears:

```
df2 = df[df['textcol'].str.contains('-') == True].copy()
df2.loc[:, ['textcol']] = df2['textcol'].str.split('-').str[0]
```

See [returning a view vs copy](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) in the `pandas` docs.