# Python Pandas: Cannot shake SettingWithCopyWarning error, even wth .loc usage

Tags: python, pandas

I've checked these existing issues:

[stack overflow .loc example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40033471/getting-settingwithcopywarning-warning-even-after-using-loc-in-pandas)

[stack overflow .loc example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38809796/pandas-still-getting-settingwithcopywarning-even-after-using-loc)

[stack overflow .loc example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622245/settingwithcopywarning-while-using-loc)

...but I don't yet grok this issue fully.

I'm trying to write a module to match strings by progressively transforming them on a source and target, and checking for additional matches. To keep track of repeated transform/match attempts, I'm using dataframes for source, target, and the matches.

So part of the resolution is to create source/target subsets for items not-yet-matched, apply the transformations, and pull out any matches that result. So my code looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def trymatch(transformers):

    global matches, source, target

    # Don't bother doing work if we've already found a match
    if matches is not None:
        s_ids = matches['id_s'].values
        s_inmask = (~source['id'].isin(s_ids))
        s = source.loc[s_inmask].copy()
        # ... do the same for the target dataframe
    else:
        s = source
        t = target

    for transformer in transformers:
        # Call the transformations here...

    mnew = pd.merge(s, t, on='matchval', suffixes=['_s', '_t'])

    if matches is None: matches = mnew
    else: matches = matches.append(mnew)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

source = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3], 'value': ['a', 'b', 'c']})
target = pd.DataFrame({'id': [4, 5, 6], 'value': ['A', 'b', 'd']})

matches = None
trymatch(['t_null'])
trymatch(['t_upper'])
```

My challenge comes with the trymatch function, where if matches already exist, I'm creating the subsets. Even with the .loc indexing, Python is throwing SettingWithCopyWarning's at me. I can get rid of them with the .copy() as I've shown here... I think this is valid because I just need temporary copies of the subsets for this function.

Does this seem valid? Could I just suppress with .is_copy = False and save memory?

Is there a more Pythonic way of approaching this problem that would side-step this issue entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've written is valid. `pandas` throws `SettingsWithCopy` warnings in cases like this one because it relies on `numpy` array semantics, which for the purpose of efficiency return *views* of data, not copies. `pandas` can't *itself* detect when this will cause a problem, hence it (conservatively) just throws this error in both good cases and bad ones.

You can get rid of the error message using:

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None  # default='warn'
```

For more details see [How to deal with SettingWithCopyWarning in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas)